# Stopping multiple threads on demand (e.g., with key input)

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pyserial

I have two serial devices that need to run at the same time: one counts particles in a water sample and the other measures the flow rate of the water sample. I need to acquire data from these serial devices until the water sample runs out; therefore, I need to stop the code (data acquisition) on demand. Currently, I have two functions (one for each device) and running them simultaneously with threads. I want to be able to stop the threads whenever the water smaple runs out. For example, I envision pressing "q" + Enter to stop the code. I am really struggling with getting the threads to behave correctly. Below is the set-up I am currently working with.

This code correctly starts data acquisition but does not wait for user input and all the code executes (i.e., the thread does not run until I press 'q' + Enter).

```
import threading
import serial

def get_AbakusData(ser):
    ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 38400, timeout=1)

    ser.write(b'C0\r\n') #initiate
    ser.write(b'C1\r\n')
    ser.write(b'C5\r\n')
    
    ser.write(b'C12\r\n')
    ser.readline()
      
    global output

    regex = r'\b0\d{7}\b'
    
    while not stop_abakus_event.is_set():  # Check if the stop_event is set
        ser.write(b'C12\r\n')  # query
        output = ser.readline()  # save output
        output = output.decode('utf-8').strip()  # convert bytes to string for regex

def get_UserInput(stop_event):
    print("Press 'q' and Enter to stop the AbakusData thread...")
    input()  # Wait for user to enter 'q' and Enter
    stop_event.set()  # Set the stop_abakus_event flag
    
stop_abakus_event = threading.Event()  # Create the threading.Event object for AbakusData

t_user_input = threading.Thread(target=get_UserInput, args=(stop_abakus_event,))
t_abakus = threading.Thread(target=get_AbakusData, args=(ser,))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    t_user_input.start()
    t_abakus.start()

    stop_abakus_event.set()
    t_user_input.join()
    t_abakus.join()
    
    ser.close()

    print('AbakusData thread stopped.')
```

Ultimately, I need to include the second device with a function called get_FlowData. I am open to other methods that are not threading; this approach just seemed to make the most sense.

EDIT: I need to do a lot of data manipulation with the data coming in. Additionally, once the data is manipulated how I need it, I store the new line of data in a SQL database. That said, I need to have a lot of flexibility with how I am handling the incoming data. An example of one of the threads I am working with is below.

```
        ser.write(b'C12\r\n')  # query
        output = ser.readline()  # save output
        output = output.decode('utf-8').strip()  # convert bytes to string for regex

        matches = re.findall(regex, output)
        output = ' '.join([match.replace(' ', '')[:8] for match in matches])
        print(output)
        output = pd.Series(output)  # convert string to series

        output = output.str.split()  # split elements by space
        bins = output.str[::2]  # odd elements are bins
        counts = output.str[1::2]  # even elements are counts
        output = {'bins': bins, 'counts': counts}  # combine lists together
        output = pd.DataFrame(output)  # make dataframe of lists

        output = pd.concat([output[col].explode().reset_index(drop=True)  # make each element of list into rows
                            for col in output], axis=1)

        # get the current time and date
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S") 
        current_date = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

        # add the current time and date to the new dataframe and append the split dataframe to it
        output['time'] = current_time
        output['date'] = current_date
        output['run_id'] = run_id

        data_output = pd.concat([data_output, output], ignore_index=True)

        data_output['bins'] = data_output['bins'].astype(int)
        data_output['counts'] = data_output['counts'].astype(int)


        data_output.to_sql('abakus_data', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)  ## add data to sql table
        conn.commit()
```

Comment: You are calling `stop_abakus_event.set()` in `if __name__ == "__main__":` in some reason. This causes `get_AbakusData` to exit immediately without waiting for user input. Comment out this line, as your code should work without it.

Comment: Hi Ken, when I remove stop_abakus_event, it indefinitely runs and my system has to restart.

Comment: Do not remove `stop_abakus_event`. Remove the line `stop_abakus_event.set()`. This is not the same.

Comment: Ken, sorry for not being clear. I removed stop_abakus_event.set() and this does not work. It makes the code run indefinitely and cannot be stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [`pyserial`](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#module-serial.threaded) threading API, as it provides a lot of useful functionality already built for you.

In particular, I would create a ReaderThread to manage your serial devices. Here's a quick example which is really just minimally modified from the example in the docs. I would use the context manager `with` to kill the existing serial connection rather than trying to create your own event.

```py
import serial
from serial.threaded import LineReader, ReaderThread
import traceback

class SensorA(LineReader):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        super().connection_made(transport)
        print('SensorA opened')
        for line in ["C0", "C1", "C5", "C12"]: #init config for sensor
            self.write_line(line)

    def handle_line(self, data): #actually do something with your data here
        if not hasattr(self, "lines"):
            self.lines = []
        self.lines.append(data) #save up the data to process later

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        if exc:
            traceback.print_exc(exc)
        print('SensorA closed')

class SensorB(LineReader):
    ...

serA = serial.Serial('COM5', 38400, timeout=1)
serB = serial.Serial('COM6', 38400, timeout=1)
with (ReaderThread(serA, SensorA) as protocolA,
      ReaderThread(serB, SensorB) as protocolB):
    while True:
        choice = input("command: ")
        if choice == "q":
            break
        elif choice == "cmdA":
            protocolA.write_line("command for A")
        elif choice == "cmdB":
            protocolB.write_line("command for B")

#when it's done:
if hasattr(protocolA, "lines"): #make sure we actually received anything
    for line in protocolA.lines:
        process(line) #do your processing
```

Edit: to generalize the title "how to stop threads?" this solution is calling `ser.read()` continuously in the ReaderThread, and when the context manager hits `__exit__`, `ser.cancel_read()` is called in the main thread. This causes `ser.read()` to exit early with an exception, which allows the thread to be `.join()`ed immediately without relying on timeouts (though including timeouts in code is not a bad idea generally).

Comment: Aaron, this behaves as I would like but I am not familiar with using classes. I am not sure where I would add my output variable (data from serial device) here and be able to manipulate it. I need to read the data, manipulate it, and add it to a growing dataframe. How would I add that in here?

Comment: I tried adding it in handle_line but no object called "output" was created.      def handle_line(self, data): 
        self.output = output

Comment: The idea is to use the `data` argument inside the `handle_line` method (which is the contents of each line from the serial device) right away. If you are simply logging the data, it could look as simple as `with open("sensor.log", "a") as f: f.write(data + "\n")` Otherwise I'd have to see how you're using this `output` variable. Using global variables to return data from a function is not a good solution in general.

Comment: I made an edit to my original post. As you can see, I have to do a series of steps to get the data how I need to store it and ultimately upload it to a SQL table with every iteration of the loop. I am unsure how this kind of manipulation fits into the code you provided.

Comment: @abbyhudak it would seem you're doing some processing on `output` before appending it to `data_output`, is that right? then when the test is over you would need to save `data_output` in some way? there are many ways to solve this, but perhaps the easiest would be to just accumulate the lines in memory and do the processing at the end (I've added this as an edit)

Comment: It could also probably be just as easy to put the processing directly into the `handle_line` function.

Comment: It didn't work underneath the `handle_line` but it is working on the `while True` loop. readerThread does not read in the same as `serial.readline()`, however, so I need to figure out how to get it to read in an entire line of data from the device.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254768/discussion-between-aaron-and-abby-hudak).